# Vue.js Life Cycle and Aggrid pagination fired is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-vue

Hello everyone thanks for your support. My problem is i am using ag-grid on vue.js and some features calling with grid api. I want to call api for using pagination feature. I called api on mounted hook but its not fired. I tried in every hook all of them doesnt work except update hooks. When the page is loaded there is pagination but if you triggered update hook the pagination comes up, it works in beforeupdate hook, well but it has to work in mounted, because first load comes without pagination.

```
  mounted() {
        //aggrid establish to api
        this.gridApi = this.gridOptions.api;   
     }
```

[image: this image without pagination so i used mounted hook]

but if i called api on beforeupdate hook. I know its wrong but just an experimental, its working

```
beforeUpdate() {
    //aggrid establish to api
    this.gridApi = this.gridOptions.api;
  }
```

[image: this image with pagination so i used on beforeupdate]

Comment: Have you tried on the `created()` hook? And maybe you need to re-render the component because this does not change any properties and it needs to refresh?

Comment: i am beginner i dont know how should i do this re-render things. I tried in every hook